# Protocol error when trying to SFTP from server to server

Tags: sftp

I am hitting a Protocol error while trying to SFTP from one server to another. I have tried to search up Google to no avail. May i know if anyone can help me with this.

```
rel@kingfisher:/kingfisher_bft/hme/rel>  sftp relst@111.32.171.172
Need basic cursor movement capability, using vt100
error: Could not open connection to `rel@111.32.171.172': Protocol error
```

Answer (score 1):

The machine you are using to sftp into the remote machine seems to be missing the `ncurses` libraries. Install them with `apt-get install libncurses5` or download them from your distributions web-page.

[ From: http://ftp.vim.org/security/ssh/README.SSH2 ]

> If your sftp2 complains something like this: "Need basic
>   cursor movement capability, using vt100", then no library
>   containing tgetent() function was found when you ran
>   ./configure . If you have a Linux system, then that is
>   probably because you don't have either termcap-devel or
>   ncurses-devel packages installed. If you want to get rid of
>   the message, and/or to use some more exotic terminals
>   capabilities, you should install either package. (A good
>   place to look for those is your distribution's web-page.)

Comment: thanks for the insights Stuffy. Could i also mention that the machine that is trying to SFTP to remote machines has no problem with other remote machines as i have tried. But the remote machine having problem is not having any issue accepting SFTP from machine...

Comment: Make sure you have the ncurses-libs on both servers. Also, try logging in with another user, and test if you can sftp from the remote server into the "kingfisher" server. And it would be useful to know what distribution you are using.

Answer (score 0):

SFTP is a subsystem of the SSH protocol, and has its own protocol. Actually there are 7 SFTP protocol versions (from 0 to 6) and 2 SSH protocol versions (SSH-1 and SSH-2).

What I see here above looks like the client and the server are unable to negotiate a common protocol, and this could be due to several reasons:

the client tries a SSH-2 connection to a server that only supports SSH-1

the client tries a SFTP protocol version that is not supported by the server

unlikely: the client tries to negotiate encryption/MAC algorithms that are unsupported by the server

In any case, I would research for the root cause of this issue on the server side.